# scikit learn classify irrelevant(out of domain) data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, bayesian

I have trained my classifier using 20 domain, using MultinomialNB.

The classifier is working fine for 20 trained datasets.

But issue is, suppose I am making query with text out of 20 domains, even though it classify that text. I expect 0 probability for out of domain input.

e.g.

Query : 'core i7 is intel processor'

And I have trained data using domain `religion`,`sports`, `astronomy` domains.

Query does not belongs to any of these domain even it gives result 33% for any of the domain.

similarly Query : 'where is what', also get classified into above domains.

How can I show 0 result for query  belonging to out of domain? or any scikit function which gives how much probability-margin is out of domains?

Also is there any way to see margin of `stopwords` in query?

Comment: You can use a threshold of confidence. 

For example you could say that if there isn't a domain in which the query at least holds 50% then it is undefined.

Comment: @AdrienNK: thanks dear, but I am looking for better solution if possible

Answer (score 1):

If you train to distinguish 3 labels, then every input will get one of these three labels.

You could train an additional label for "everything that cannot be classified into religion, sports, astronomy".

Then you can use that label as "detected out-of-domain".

Comment: thanks, but as I have 20 domains and having dataset belonging to these domains. Getting data which does not belongs to these 20 domain is infeasible : )

Comment: Is there any dataset which classify stop words?

Comment: If you train a classifier, usually that classifier will classify based on a predicted (conditional) probability of your input. You can experimentally find out a threshold for this probability. Below that you do not accept even if the class is the best of all classes. This gives you "classify as out of domain" for free, but of course setting such a threshold is risky and has to be done carefully.

Comment: Stopwords are usually just lists of words that are ignored as they are frequent function-words which bear no semantic content. You can find stop-word lists online, for example here http://www.link-assistant.com/seo-stop-words.html and here http://www.semantikoz.com/blog/free-stop-word-lists-in-23-languages/

Comment: @ peschü: yeah, putting threshold I really don't prefer. Thanks for stopwards, I tried ignoring all stopwords, but even though it was classifying query like `what is where` to specific domain

Comment: I applied one more hack, put all `stopwords` as one of class, but in that case also it was classifying such query into other classes